# Error while adding a new column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ddl

I'm trying to add a new column called `buy` to my table `book`. I tried using this SQL statement:

```
ALTER TABLE book 
    ALTER COLUMN buy INT;
```

But I'm getting an error:

> There is already an object named 'book' in the database

Comment: you wouldn't get that error message from that code. Looks like you must be running a `CREATE ... book` also

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add the column, the syntax is

```
alter table book add Buy int;
```

If the column already existed, you might use `alter` to change its data type, for example,

```
alter table book alter column Buy smallint;
```

See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 1):

You are not altering the column rather adding one.
The syntax for SQL Server is:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD column_name data_type column_constraint;
```

Since you don't have any constraint to declare you need to do:

```
ALTER TABLE book add buy INT;
```

If you want this column to be `not null` then your syntax will be:

```
ALTER TABLE book add buy INT not NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to *add* a column:

```
ALTER TABLE book ADD buy INT;
```